# Cumulative count by group in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to generate in DAX a cumulative counting, group by another column like the example below. The second column is what I want to achieve. I've tried to do some calculations but nothing is working

| Value | Cumulative Counting by Group |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| C | 2 |

Answer (score 2):

One significant issue you may be running into is that tables etc don't have a defined order. I forced an order by adding an index to your table. (if you right-click the table, click on Edit Query, and then click on the dropdown at the very top left of the table, you'll get a menu of options. Select Add Index Column (I started from 1). Then I can create a measure like this:

```
Running Count = COUNTROWS(
           FILTER(
               ALL('Valores'),
               'Valores'[Index]<=MAX('Valores'[Index]) &&
               'Valores'[Value] = MAX('Valores'[Value])
           )
```

)

In English, it's removing the filters from the 'valores' table., and then counting the rows where the [Value] column (A, B, C...) is the same as the "current" value and the Index column value is less than the "current" value. (meaning the value in the current row).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pieter! I've already solved it. Your calculation it's almost right. Instead of writting MAX, you need to create an external row context. One method is using variables, like this:

```
Running Count = 

VAR current_index = 'Valores'[Index]
VAR current_value = 'Valores'[Value]

RETURN

COUNTROWS(
           FILTER(
               ALL('Valores'),
               'Valores'[Index] <= current_index &&
               'Valores'[Value] = current_value
           )
)
```